# How to mapping a multiple type javascript array to C# array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use asp.net MVC model binding to accept the parameters for ajax.

I have an object, it's data structure like this:

```
{
      "conditions": [
        {
          "field": "",
          "opreator": "",
          "value": ""
        },[{
          "field": "",
          "opreator": "",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "field": "",
          "opreator": "",
          "value": ""
        }]
      ],
      "name": "query",
}
```

C# array can't has different types. (the property conditions is an arrray that has object and array).

So I defined an object array.

```
public class QueryVM
{
    public class condition
    {
        public string field { get; set; }
        public string opreator { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public object[] conditions { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

But what I received the property conditions is just an object array. I can't access it's actual property, I even don't know it's actual type is(`QueryVM.condition` or `array`). I thinks the model binding even not set value of the properties. So this is a bad way.

I want know whether there is other way to do this?

**UPDATE**

The `conditions` property of `QueryVM` is an object array because it's contain object and array.

Comment: Field conditions should be of type condition[] not object[], also, this is not a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

Conditions should be an array of type condition instead of simple object.

Try replacing

```
public object[] conditions { get; set; }
```

with

```
public condition[] conditions { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you are sending list of type object because the type is not defined so you can do something like this

```
public List<object> conditions { get; set; }
```

this will get the list but your json should be like this

```
conditions:[{
          "field": "",
          "opreator": "",
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "field": "",
          "opreator": "",
          "value": ""
        }]
```

and your then your type will be

```
public List<condition> conditions { get; set; }
```